# SQL client on client machine for Desktop application

Tags: sql, windows, sqlclient

I m deploying desktop inventory application on client Windows 7 32 bit machine.
We used .Net framework 4 and SQL Server database. SQL Server 2008 not able to install on Windows 7 Home edition.,
Is it possible to install only SQL CLient on client machine ?

Answer (score 1):

See if you install only the sql client, then you will need to provide some server to fetch the data from. Try keeping the data on some remote server (maybe the clients corporate server) and install clients on machines requiring it. This way, your data is centralized and you save yourself the trouble of installing the server on every machine.

Comment: thnks fr ans.. Where do we get SQL Client .. Can you please suggest links ?.

Comment: try [this link](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpublib.boulder.ibm.com%2Finfocenter%2Fdb2luw%2Fv9%2Ftopic%2Fcom.ibm.db2.udb.uprun.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0023452.htm&ei=nAgnUsD6Js3orQeAh4D4CQ&usg=AFQjCNETFrIGXEK6Qzq7h_Z33f9-GGeMSw&sig2=5cFEZA2Wrzy1i6O-r7eQXA&bvm=bv.51495398,d.bmk)

Comment: tell me one that ..Is it needed to install sql server on client machine for dtabase connection or sql client... ?

Comment: The job of client is to ask the server for data and present it to whoever generated the query. So on client machine, you should have only the client. Server should ideally be unified.

Comment: can you provide details of client for SQL Server